# Erasing row in 2D Vector - segmentation error

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C++, and am learning vectors now. I'm trying to delete a row from a 2D vector, but so far all my attempts have been resulting in a segmemtation error. This is the piece of code I've been trying out -

```
vector<vector<int> > myVector;
...
vector<vector<int> >::iterator row = myVector.begin();
while(row!=myVector.end())
{
    if((*row)[0] == -1)
        myVector.erase(row);
    else
        row++;
}
```

myVector is a 2D vector that contains values such as:

```
 1 0
-1 1
 2 1
-1 0 ...
```

I need to delete any row whose first element is -1.

I've tried using `myVector.erase(myVector.begin() + row2delete)` but that's giving me a core dump too. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you for the help!

Comment: does my answer work fine for you?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I have another question though. All those rows were deleted, and the vector now has 13 elements. But vector.size() says it has 19. Why is that?

Comment: Strange. Which approach? Can you post the link to your entire running code below my answer? You can run your code on www.ideone.com and post the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it. You cannot completely erase an item from a `vector` while iterating over it with an `iterator` at the same time as it would *invalidate* the `iterator`. However, you could have `myVector[i].clear()` but that would not delete that row entirely. To do what you want, I can suggest 2 approaches:

```cpp
vector<vector<int> > v(100); //Allocate space for 100 vectors

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    v[i].resize(100); //set the size of these 100 vectors to say 100 again

vector<int> indices; //This vector will store the indices of the vectors which have 1st element as -1
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) //iterator through vector storing vecgtors
    if(v[i].size()>0 && v[i][0]==-1) //Condition check
        indices.push_back(i); //add these indices you want to delete. *You cannot delete while looping

for(int i=0;i<indices.size();i++) //Now, delete them
    v.erase(v.begin()+indices[i]);
```

Here, you had to iterate twice and it isn't exactly what you needed. A smarter way would be to keep a count variable controlled by a while loop which does not increase the parent container's size. You are basically iterating in a non-linear fashion here. Here's how:

```cpp
vector<vector<int> > v(100); //Allocate space for 100 vectors

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    v[i].resize(100); //set the size of these 100 vectors to say 100 again

int cnt=0; //Keep a counter variable
while(cnt<v.size())
{
    if(v[cnt].size()>0 && v[cnt][0]==-1)
        v.erase(v.begin()+cnt); //Do not increment count here! As the vector next comes here now after resizing
    else
        cnt++;
}
//Done!
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault you are experiencing comes from the fact that .erase() invalidates the iterator. That is why erase returns an iterator so that you can use that as next iterator.

To delete a row in a 2-dim vector you could do something like this (I use std::array to get a fixed size in the declaration)

```
std::vector<std::array<int,100>> dim2(100);

std::cout << dim2.size() << std::endl;

dim2[10][10] = 100001;
std::cout << dim2[10][10] << std::endl;

dim2.erase(dim2.begin()+9); // erase the 10th row

std::cout << dim2.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << dim2[10][10] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

> `iterator erase (iterator position);`
>
> Iterators, pointers and references pointing to `position` and beyond are invalidated...

When you do `myVector.erase(row)`, the iterator `row` is invalidated, so that on the next loop iteration, the attempt to compare / dereference it breaks.

`vector::erase()` returns an iterator to the element following the one that was erased, so you probably wanted to do `row = myVector.erase(row);`

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is make another 2D vector and shift all the elements which do not have -1 as first element to the new vector and after that when shifting is complete delete the first vector.
For eg:-

```
vector<vector<int> > myVector;vector<vector<int> > myVector2;
int i=0;
while(i<myVector.size()){
    if(myVector[i][0] != -1){
        myVector2.push_back(myVector[i]);
}
return myVector2;
```